# Python 2.7 code for Replacing whole value of a column in a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, filewriter

I have a data imported from SQL server in a csv file with headers.

I want to write a **code in python2.7 ** which can read a csv file and re-write it into new csv file in which we have masked last 2 columns with a regex like 'SECRET VALUE'.

**Sample Input of CSV:**

```
ID,Name,city,SSN,CreditCardNo
1,Joy,London,123-465-456,123456789087645
2,Sam,NewYork,765-465-457,98765434567345
3,Jhon,Paris,678-365-654,765654542345677
4,Eric,Delhi,456-888-999,123456789087645
```

**Expected sample output:**

```
ID,Name,city,SSN,CreditCardNo
1,Joy,London,SECRET VALUE,SECRET VALUE
2,Sam,NewYork,SECRET VALUE,SECRET VALUE
3,Jhon,Paris,SECRET VALUE,SECRET VALUE
4,Eric,Delhi,SECRET VALUE,SECRET VALUE
```

My attempt:

```
import sys
import csv

r = csv.reader(open('C:\\Users\\Praveen\\workspace\\sampleFiles\\test1.csv'))
lines = [l for l in r]

lines[2][2] = '30'

writer = csv.writer(open('C:\\Users\\Praveen\\workspace\\sampleFiles\\test4.csv', 'wb'))
writer.writerows(lines)
```

This changes one element only, i want the whole column to be masked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) first, then replace values with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and last write to file by [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""ID,Name,city,SSN,CreditCardNo
1,Joy,London,123-465-456,123456789087645
2,Sam,NewYork,765-465-457,98765434567345
3,Jhon,Paris,678-365-654,765654542345677
4,Eric,Delhi,456-888-999,123456789087645"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print df
   ID  Name     city          SSN     CreditCardNo
0   1   Joy   London  123-465-456  123456789087645
1   2   Sam  NewYork  765-465-457   98765434567345
2   3  Jhon    Paris  678-365-654  765654542345677
3   4  Eric    Delhi  456-888-999  123456789087645

df.iloc[:, -2:] = 'SECRET VALUE'
print df
   ID  Name     city           SSN  CreditCardNo
0   1   Joy   London  SECRET VALUE  SECRET VALUE
1   2   Sam  NewYork  SECRET VALUE  SECRET VALUE
2   3  Jhon    Paris  SECRET VALUE  SECRET VALUE
3   4  Eric    Delhi  SECRET VALUE  SECRET VALUE

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael it solves the functionality i was looking for.